# dropdownlist in gridview , selected Value doesn't change

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

It seems a very simple issue but it has killed my day.
I have an update-able  gridview and I put a dropdownlist in the edit mode of one of the columns.  The items in the DDL is statically set. BUT the selected item always remains the first item. How can I fix this?

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string userID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbluserID")).Text;

    string role = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedValue;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = DBSettings.sqlConn;
    cmd.CommandText = "Update tbl_users set role=@role , pending='false' ,approved='true' , declined='false' where ID=@ID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", role);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    gridFill();
}
```

here is the aspx of the gridView (only the ddl part):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Value="">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Admin" Text="Admin"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Editor" Text="Editor"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Viewer" Text="Viewer"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="pending"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is without seeing your GridView databinding code, but I think you did not wrap the dababinding in a IsPostBack check.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = yourSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

If you did not do this, the GridView will be rebuild from scratch and the DropDownList will be set to it's default position.